# Binary number to ASCII number converter doesnt work (PyVersion 3.6.4)

Tags: python

I tried to code a programm that converts binary numbers to Ascii numbers. Butt it doesnt work. It always spits out a zero.
Here is my code:

```
import math

Bin = input("")
WordCounter = 0
PowerOfTwo = 0
BinNum = 0

while(True):
  try:
    BinNum += ((Bin[WordCounter]) * math.pow(2, PowerOfTwo))
    WordCounter += 1
    PowerOfTwo += 1
  except: break

print(BinNum)
```

Comment: what are ascii numbers? what are you trying to achieve? please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I think op is trying to convert binary to decimal `11111111 to 255`

Comment: my point is: people trying to answer should not have to guess... there should be a clear problem statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Bin[WordCounter]` has type `str`, a string. you need to wrap it in `int` like so

```
BinNum += int(Bin[WordCounter]) * math.pow(2, PowerOfTwo)
```

(although your code will still produce a result that is backwards, you'll need to think about that)

---

The thing is, if you hadn't hidden the exception with a bare `except`, you would have got a very useful error message

```
BinNum += (Bin[WordCounter]) * math.pow(2, PowerOfTwo)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-d38cc5b7069c> in <module>()
----> 1 BinNum += (Bin[WordCounter]) * math.pow(2, PowerOfTwo)

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

---

Also, please read [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) so you follow the python style guidelines.

---

Fine, because I'm feeling generous, the solution to your problem (other than just `bin_num = int(input(""), 2)`, is:

```
bin_ = input("")

bin_num = 0
for index, char in enumerate(reversed(bin_)):
    bin_num += int(char) * 2**index  # ** is the power operator

print(bin_num)
```

Explanation:

```
enumerate('abcd') --> (0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd')
reversed('abcd') --> 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a'
```

Comment: @hiroprotagonist sure. But I don't want to do the whole thing for them. OP is clearly just a beginner.

Comment: If he hadn't hidden the exception as simply `except`, he would also get an infinite 'loop' of  `IndexError: string index out of range`

Comment: Thanks for that fast respond :D Now going to rework my code

Comment: Just noticed that u didnt define result. Did you mean print(bin_num) instead?

Comment: @Prometheus sorry, `result` was a previous name I used, it should be `bin_num`.

Comment: I found out that I can use the bin() function provided by py it self xD

Comment: @Prometheus `bin` does the opposite of what you were trying to do. `int('101010', 2)` converts a binary string to a decimal integer.